# How to fix missing game object on android build on some devices?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. My Android build doesn't work properly on SOME devices. I mean, that I tested the app on 8 different phones, and I cannot see the relation between Android version (2 devices on Android 6. One of them works fine, the second one doesn't). Also, one device is Honor (works), the second one Honor (doesn't). Two Lenovo phones does not work.

I tried

```
- upgrading Android API to level 28 (SDK), 
- "Use 32-bit display buffer", "Disable depth and Stencil" turned on and off, 
- tried materials and textures with cube,
- turned off the objects animator
```

[image: How it looks like][image: How it should be]
[image: Game Object structure][image: The main texture of the object]

I just have no idea what can I do. If someone could help me, it would be very nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I spent something about 7 hours of checking all the settings on/off and find the answer.
Just need to check OFF the "GPU skinning" in Player Settings